# How to remove user installed packages from system Python on macOS Sonoma safely?

Tags: python, macos, dependencies

I have accidentally installed Pygame for my system-wide Python (i.e., using `pip3` which has path `/usr/bin/pip3`). I have read somewhere that it is a good practice to keep system Python clean. I want to remove Pygame and all of its dependencies from my system Python. How can I do that safely?

I find this solution `pip3 freeze > to_delete.txt` and `pip3 uninstall -y -r to_delete.txt`, but I am afraid to accidentally remove packages that are actually needed by system (like perhaps `macholib` which is in my `to_delete.txt`).

Is there a way to remove only user-installed packages from system Python on macOS safely?

Comment: make venv, install pygame on it; do pip freeze to see all the packages it installed, deactivate venv; remove packages that showed up in venv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) package is really helpful to see what is happening with your dependencies:

`pip install pipdeptree`

to run it once installed:

`pipdeptree`

Here is an example output:

```
Django==5.0.2
├── asgiref [required: >=3.7.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
└── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
pip==23.2.1
pipdeptree==2.15.1
pygame==2.5.2
```

You can see that Django depends on some other packages, but in fact `pygame` does not. If your version of pygame also has no dependencies then you should be safe to just:

`pip uninstall pygame && pip uninstall pipdeptree`